# How to use an aggregate measure in my WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql

```
select distinct hash, title, count(*) as c
from pastes 
where hash is not null  
group by hash, title 
order by c desc;
```

I'm able to sort the results of this query based on the 'c' column I defined on-the-fly in the query.

But I'd also like to add c to the WHERE clause:

```
select distinct hash, title, count(*) as c 
from pastes 
where c > 10 and hash is not null  
group by hash, title 
order by c desc;

ERROR:  column "c" does not exist
LINE 1: ...inct hash, title, count(*) as c from pastes where c > 10 and...
                                                             ^
```

What is the right way to specify a query like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions on aggregates are done using `having`

```
select hash, title, count(*) as c 
from pastes 
where hash is not null  
group by hash, title 
having count(*) > 10
order by c desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap it as a subquery:

```
select q.* from (
select hash, title, count(*) as c 
from pastes where hash is not null  
group by hash, title 
) q
where q.c > 10 
order by q.c desc;
```

You could skip the subquery and use HAVING as opposed to WHERE, but I see you also need to ORDER BY c, hence the subquery.

Comment: The HAVING subclause does seem to work with the order by c.